# Large file upload fails on node.js Hapi

Tags: android, node.js, typescript, upload, hapi.js

I have a node.js script which should handle file uploads, also multiple at once. Uploading pictures and voices work just fine. However, video files at around 10 MB or larger do not upload. Sometimes it doesn't work at all and sometimes it gets stuck in the `fs.writeFile` function. Maybe there is a better way general as I came up with many parts in the code on my own. I need the md5 hash before creating the file on disk because its path will be generated from the hash. Also I get a SocketTimeoutException on the Android side. Code is mainly focused on that part right now, so don't worry about the missing input validation and onProgress.

NodeJS:

```
server.route({
method: 'POST',
path: '/uploadFile',
config: {
    payload: {
        output: 'stream',
        allow: 'multipart/form-data',
        maxBytes: 100*1024*1024 //100 mb

    }
}, handler: async function (request, reply)
{
    await incoming_uploadFile(request, reply);
}
});

...........

var joi = require('joi');
import { Paths } from "../util/Paths";
import * as fs from 'fs';

let data;
let numOfFiles: number;

export async function incoming_uploadFile(request, reply) {

data = request.payload;
await Application.InitializeSocket(null, "UploadFile");
let userID = await Application.AuthUser(JSON.parse(data['auth']));


numOfFiles = parseInt(data['numOfFiles']);


if (numOfFiles > 0)
    upload(0);

}

async function upload(i: number)
{


    const file = data['file' + i];
    const meta = data['fileMeta' + i];
    const metaJson = Application.StringToJson(meta);

    const fileType: string = metaJson['fileType'];
    const extension: string = metaJson['extension'];
    var crypto = require('crypto');

    const md5 = crypto.createHash('md5');

    var length = parseInt(file.hapi.headers["content-length"]);

    let buffer: Buffer = new Buffer(length);
    let bufPos : number = 0;
    file.on('data', function (b : Uint8Array) {
        for (var i = 0; i < b.byteLength; ++i)
            buffer.writeUInt8(b[i], bufPos++);

    });

    file.on('end', function (err) {

        var hash = md5.update(buffer.toString("base64")).digest("hex");
        const filePath: string = Paths.getFilePath(hash, fileType, extension);

        // Creates all dirs that are missing on the path
        var shell = require('shelljs');
        shell.mkdir('-p', require('path').dirname(filePath));

        console.log("writing buffer to file...");

        fs.writeFile(filePath, buffer,null);

        if ((++i) < numOfFiles)
            upload(i);




    });

}
```

Android uploading the file(s):

```
 public static void uploadAttachments(ArrayList<EventAttachment> attachments)
{

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    // Add attachments
    MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder();
    builder.setType(MultipartBody.FORM);
    builder.addFormDataPart("numOfFiles",String.valueOf(attachments.size()));

    for (int i = 0; i < attachments.size();++i) {
        EventAttachment attachment = attachments.get(i);
        File file = new File(attachment.getPath());
        String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(attachment.getPath());
        String type = null;
        if (extension != null) {
            type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
        } else {

            Log.e("x", "Could not get extensions of file " + file.getAbsolutePath() + ". File upload aborted.");
            return;
        }

        ProgressRequestBody p = new ProgressRequestBody(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(type), file), new ProgressRequestBody.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(int progress) {

            }
        });

        builder.addFormDataPart("file" + i, file.getName(), p);
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
        hm.put("extension", extension.replace(".", ""));
        hm.put("fileType", String.valueOf(attachment.getType()));
        builder.addFormDataPart("fileMeta" + i, new JSONObject(hm).toString());


    }
    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
        builder.addFormDataPart("auth", putDefaultHeader(jObj).toString());
        MultipartBody mb = builder.build();


        okhttp3.Request request = new Request.Builder().url(EndPoint+UPLOAD_FILE).post(mb).build();


        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

                Log.e("x", "Error uploading file");
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

            }
        });





}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added

`timeout: false,
 parse: true`

on the config payload and works for now.